# Pronunciation of "cold" and "code" in American English

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

In British English the difference is clear, but do these words "cold" and "code" also sound different in American English? If so, how does one make /oʊ/ different from /oʊǀ/? Do the lips round more for /oʊǀ/?

Comment: It all depends on the speaker's accent. I think I'd have trouble distinguishing these two words in [Mancunian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_dialect), and that's a ***British*** accent (Manchester-based).

Comment: My lips stay the same, but my tongue curls to insert the "l" in _cold_.

Comment: Well and the "o" is also pronounced differently, at least in my accent. *Ode* and *old* don't sound the same; neither do *code* and *cold*. The vowel sound is different, not just the "l".

Comment: My native dialect is East Alabama, and unless I'm in onstage mode I pronounce them identically.

Comment: I'm from Texas, and the tongue hits the palate for the "l" in *cold*.

Comment: In my personal idiolect, I think they're both diphthongs, where the second element is pretty much **ʊ** (as in *book*). The first element in *cold* seems to be the same vowel as in *hot*, but I'm not sure about the first element in *code*. It seems to be just a neutral vowel/schwa. I certainly wouldn't enunciate the **L** in *cold* in normal circumstances.

Comment: A slight correction: I pronounce the *noun* "cold" like *code*; the adjective is /koʊ/, unless there's liaison. We mostly delete terminal /l/.

Comment: @StoneyB Interesting! I don't know how to represent it in symbols, but I always pronounce the *l* in *cold*. For the vowels, *code* is an *oh* sound, but in *cold* it's more like *uhl*. Which may or may not make sense when spoken aloud by someone who isn't me, haha. I thought of another way to explain it; take the word *kohl* and add a *d* to the end of the pronunciation, and that's how I say *cold*.

Comment: @WendiKidd In my dialect, kohl (or coal) would be /koʊ/, same as cold. There's no /l/ unless a vowel follows it, so Remarque's novel is *Aw Quiet onna Western Front*, but Warren's novel is *Awla King's Men*.

Comment: @WendiKidd I think you're describing the difference between `/koʊld/` and `/kl̩d/`.  @chrylis The American L varies.  In my `/l/`, the tip of my tongue **doesn't** touch the roof of my mouth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the responses in the comments:

In many dialects, both British and US, [ɫ], the ‘dark’ post-vocalic variant of the phoneme /l/ is reduced.

> Following an unrounded vowel, it becomes a longish offglide [ʊː]:  standard [kɪɫ] (*kill*) becomes [kɪʊː].
>
> Following a vowel which already has this offglide, it lengthens the offglide:  standard [kɔʊɫ] (*coal*) becomes [kɔʊː], standard [kaʊɫ] (*cowl*) becomes [kaʊː].
>
> Following a rounded vowel, it may either reduce to an offglide [ʊː], often with some reduction of the base vowel for more contrast—standard [kɔɫ] (*call*) becomes [kəʊː] in my dialect—or it may simply lengthen the base vowel:  standard [kɔɫ] becomes [kɔː].

These changes are not affected by a following consonant, so standard [kɔʊɫd] (*cold*) becomes [kɔʊːd]. The only difference between *cold* and *code*, then, is that the [ʊ] piece is slightly longer with *cold*.

Note, however, that these changes do not take place (at least in my dialect) when phonemic /l/ is followed by a vowel, as in *calling*. In this case, /l/ becomes the beginning of the following syllable; in that syllable-initial context it loses its ‘darkness’ and is pronounced as [l]: ['kɔ⋅lɪŋ]

Comment: And here is a video that demonstrates one way to pronounce both words in the US: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LR_AhXb8tTg

Answer (score -2):

Yes, they're distinct in US English.  At least on the West Coast, we pronounce cold "cohld" and code as "cohd", both with a hard "o".